# How to get a datatable or other object a list with the intersection of one List<object> and one dataview

Tags: c#, datatable

I have one DataTable

```
Datatable dt;
```

There are 10 columns there, including the ID of the row.

And in the view state I have a generic list like:

```
List<MyObject>;
```

Myobject has some fields including the same ID.

The datatable has ALL items, and the list has a reduced list of those items.
However my gridview needs to be bound to a datatable, not to a List

The question is how can I get into one new Datatable (with same columns as the first one) with all items from the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Linq:

```
var rowsInList  = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  join obj in objectList
                  on row.Field<int>("ID") equals obj.ID
                  select row;
DataTable filtered = rowsInList.CopyToDataTable();
```

`Enumerable.Join` is efficient since it's using a set. Due to LINQ's deferred execution `rowsInList` is just a "no-op"-query which gets executed at `CopyToDataTable`.

Another, less efficient, approach is using `Where` + `Any` (here with method syntax):

```
DataTable filtered = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => objectList.Any(o => row.Field<int>("ID") == o.ID))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```